# scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve and multiplying Fourier Transforms give different results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

Here's my code:

```
from scipy.ndimage import filters
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[2,43,42,123,461],[453,12,111,123,55] ,[123,112,233,12,255]])
b = numpy.array([[0,2,2,3,0],[0,15,12,100,0],[0,45,32,22,0]])

ab = filters.convolve(a,b, mode='constant', cval=0)

af = numpy.fft.fftn(a)
bf = numpy.fft.fftn(b)

abf = af*bf

abif = numpy.fft.ifftn(abf)

print numpy.around(ab)
print numpy.around(abif)
```

The results are:

```
[[ 1599  2951  7153 13280 18311]
 [ 8085 51478 13028 40239 30964]
 [18192 32484 23527 36122  8726]]

[[ 37416.+0.j  32251.+0.j  46375.+0.j  32660.+0.j  23986.+0.j]
 [ 30265.+0.j  33206.+0.j  62450.+0.j  19726.+0.j  17613.+0.j]
 [ 40239.+0.j  38095.+0.j  24492.+0.j  51478.+0.j  13028.+0.j]]
```

How can I fix my way of doing convolution using FFT so to guarantee that it gives the same result as `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @senderle points out, when you use the FFT to implement the convolution, you get the *circular* convolution.  @senderle's answer shows how to adjust the arguments of `filters.convolve` to do a circular convolution. To modify the FFT calculation to generate the same result as your original use of `filters.convolve`, you can pad the arguments with 0, and then extract the appropriate part of the result:

```
from scipy.ndimage import filters
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[2.0,43,42,123,461], [453,12,111,123,55], [123,112,233,12,255]])
b = numpy.array([[0.0,2,2,3,0], [0,15,12,100,0], [0,45,32,22,0]])

ab = filters.convolve(a,b, mode='constant', cval=0)

print numpy.around(ab)
print

nrows, ncols = a.shape
# Assume b has the same shape as a.
# Pad the bottom and right side of a and b with zeros.
pa = numpy.pad(a, ((0, nrows-1), (0, ncols-1)), mode='constant')
pb = numpy.pad(b, ((0, nrows-1), (0, ncols-1)), mode='constant')
paf = numpy.fft.fftn(pa)
pbf = numpy.fft.fftn(pb)
pabf = paf*pbf
p0 = nrows // 2
p1 = ncols // 2
pabif = numpy.fft.ifftn(pabf).real[p0:p0+nrows, p1:p1+ncols]

print pabif
```

Output:

```
[[  1599.   2951.   7153.  13280.  18311.]
 [  8085.  51478.  13028.  40239.  30964.]
 [ 18192.  32484.  23527.  36122.   8726.]]

[[  1599.   2951.   7153.  13280.  18311.]
 [  8085.  51478.  13028.  40239.  30964.]
 [ 18192.  32484.  23527.  36122.   8726.]]
```

Comment: It's also instructive to look at the source code for [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L350) which shows that the native fft-based convolution is performing this padding (to nearest powers of two) automatically, and when the shape of the output is requested to be `'same'` (matching the input shape), it extracts the relevant sub-portion of the result.

Comment: I was just about to add a link to `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`, but you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 5):

This turned out to be a fascinating question. It seems that convolution using the Discrete Fourier Transform (as implemented by `numpy.fft.fftn`) is equivalent to a [circular convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Functions_of_discrete_variable_sequences). So all we need to do is use the `'wrap'` convolution mode, and set the origin appropriately:

```
>>> filters.convolve(a, b, mode='wrap', origin=(-1, -2))
array([[37416, 32251, 46375, 32660, 23986],
       [30265, 33206, 62450, 19726, 17613],
       [40239, 38095, 24492, 51478, 13028]])
>>> numpy.fft.ifftn(numpy.fft.fftn(a) * numpy.fft.fftn(b))
array([[ 37416.+0.j,  32251.+0.j,  46375.+0.j,  32660.+0.j,  23986.+0.j],
       [ 30265.+0.j,  33206.+0.j,  62450.+0.j,  19726.+0.j,  17613.+0.j],
       [ 40239.+0.j,  38095.+0.j,  24492.+0.j,  51478.+0.j,  13028.+0.j]])
>>> (filters.convolve(a, b, mode='wrap', origin=(-1, -2)) ==
...  numpy.around(numpy.fft.ifftn(numpy.fft.fftn(a) * numpy.fft.fftn(b))))
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The difference has only to do with the way `filters.convolve` handles edges. A way to use `fftn` to perform convolution in other modes didn't strike me right away; for a clever (and hindsight-obvious) approach to that problem, see [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469015/577088)'s excellent answer.