# using Fourier transforms to do convolution?

Tags: python, numpy, filter, fft, convolution

According to the [Convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Convolution_theorem_for_inverse_Fourier_transform), we can convert the Fourier transform operator to convolution.

Using Python and Scipy, my code is below but not correct.
Can you help me and explain it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from scipy import signal

from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np

x = [[1 , 2] , [7 , 8]]

y = [[4 , 5] , [3 , 4]]


print "conv:" ,  signal.convolve2d(x , y , 'full')

new_x = np.fft.fft2(x)
new_y = np.fft.fft2(y)


print "fft:" , np.fft.ifft2(np.dot(new_x , new_y))
```

The result of code:

```
conv: [[ 4 13 10]
 [31 77 48]
 [21 52 32]]

fft: [[  20.+0.j   26.+0.j]
 [ 104.+0.j  134.+0.j]]
```

I'm confused!

Comment: Are you aware of [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html)?

Comment: I don't have scipy, so I don't know what output it's producing. You should add the output of your code to your question. Were you hoping Numpy to produce `[[ 67.  65.] [ 79.  77.]]` ?

Comment: I don't know scipy.signal.fftconvolve.thanks.

Comment: @PM2Ring,Yes , I hope that result as [[4 13  10] [31 77 48] [21 52 32]] , not you say.

Comment: @user7138814 thanks , this method is useful, and the result is same as conv2d.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468307/scipy-ndimage-filters-convolve-and-multiplying-fourier-transforms-give-different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be in the discrepancy between the discrete and continuous convolutions. The convolution kernel (i.e. y) will extend beyond the boundaries of x, and these regions need accounting for in the convolution.

scipy.signal.convolve will by default pad the out of bounds regions with 0s, which will bias results:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html

The Fourier multiplication will not do this by default - you could test this by making padded x, y arrays and comparing the results.

The discrepancy between such techniques should diminish as the kernel size becomes much less than the image dimensions.

As a further note - you should not use the dot product between new_x, new_y. Instead, just multiply the arrays with the * operator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The distinction is not discrete vs. continuous; it is circular vs. padded.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468307/scipy-ndimage-filters-convolve-and-multiplying-fourier-transforms-give-different

Answer (score 3):

I answer my question.
The correct code.

```
import sys
from scipy import signal

from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np

x = [[1 , 0 , 0 , 0] , [0 , -1 , 0 , 0] , [0 , 0 , 3 , 0] , [0 , 0 , 0 , 1]]
x = np.array(x)
y = [[4 , 5] , [3 , 4]]
y = np.array(y)

print "conv:" ,  signal.convolve2d(x , y , 'full')

s1 = np.array(x.shape)
s2 = np.array(y.shape)

size = s1 + s2 - 1


fsize = 2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(size)).astype(int)
fslice = tuple([slice(0, int(sz)) for sz in size])


new_x = np.fft.fft2(x , fsize)


new_y = np.fft.fft2(y , fsize)
result = np.fft.ifft2(new_x*new_y)[fslice].copy()

print "fft for my method:" , np.array(result.real , np.int32)

print "fft:" , np.array(signal.fftconvolve(x ,y) , np.int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the correct code. A quick question: what is the source/book/lecture that tells you how to calculate: size, fsize and fslice?

Comment: I am almost sure this fsize has to be with the fact that fft computes MUCH faster if the size if a "power of two" (2^n). Therefore, if you have a size 1000, he makes it 1024 to compute faster and then the fslice is to cut the extra 24 values on the result.

Comment: Why this computes much faster for those cases can be easily understood with any tutorial on how the fft works (I am talking the algorithm to compute the fft, not the fourier transform theory itself).