# Distribution of pairwise distances between many integers

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

We have M unique integers between 1 and N. In real life, N is a few millions, and M is between N/10 and N/3. I need to compute a distribution of pairwise distances between the M integers.

The brute-force complexity of the problem is M^2, but the output is just N numbers. So the natural question is whether there is a faster algorithm. Even an algorithm as fast as N * sqrt(M) should be sufficient for our purposes.

The problem appeared as a subset of the following problem. We have a large virtual square symmetric matrix, few million by few million elements. Some rows and columns of the matrix are masked out. We need to find how many masked-out elements are in each diagonal of the matrix. One can easily calculate how many masked-out bins intersect each diagonal. But often a masked-out row and column would intersect right on the diagonal, thus masking out only one bin. To avoid double-counting these, we need pairwise distribution of distances between masked-out columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in O(NlogN) using the Fourier transform.

The idea is that you first compute a histogram H(x) of your M integers where H(x) is the number of times the value x appears in your input (which will be either 0 or 1 if all M are distinct - but this is not essential).

Then what you want to compute is A(d), where A(d) defined as the number of pairs of integers that are exactly d apart.

This can be computed as A(d) = sum(H(x)*H(x+d) for all x)

This type of function is called a convolution and can be efficiently computed by taking the Fourier transform, multiplying the output by itself, and then computing the inverse transform.  Care needs to be taken to pad appropriately, for example see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468307/scipy-ndimage-filters-convolve-and-multiplying-fourier-transforms-give-different).

If you use Python, this is particularly easy as you can call [scipy.signal.fftconvolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) to do this operation.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed obvious after reading your answer. I just somehow missed it...