# Convolution product in pyFFTW different from scipy

Tags: python, scipy, convolution, fftw, pyfftw

I'm trying to implement a FFT convolution that mimics `scipy.fftconvolve` using pyfftw for performance and pictures as input :

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw
a = np.ones((6000, 4000), dtype='float32')
b = np.kaiser(25, 8)
b = np.outer(b, b).astype('float32')

class fftconvolve:
    def __init__(self, A, B, domain, threads=8):
        MK =  B.shape[0]
        NK = B.shape[1]
        M = A.shape[0]
        N = A.shape[1]

        if domain =="same":
            Y = M
            X = N
        elif domain == "valid":
            Y = M - MK + 1
            X = N - NK + 1
        elif domain == "full":
            Y = M + MK - 1
            X = N + NK - 1

        self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfft2(A, s=(M + MK -1, N + NK -1), threads=threads)
        self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfft2(B, s=(M + MK -1, N + NK -1), threads=threads)
        self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.irfft2(self.fft_A_obj.output_array, s=(Y, X), threads=threads)

    def __call__(self, A, B):
        return self.ifft_obj(np.fft.ifftshift(
            np.fft.fftshift(self.fft_A_obj(A)) * np.fft.fftshift(self.fft_B_obj(B))
        ))
```

Calling it :

```
plan = fftconvolve(a, b, "full", threads=8)
c_1 = plan(a, b)
c_1
```

Output :

```
array([[  3.89971137e-06,   3.51986018e-05,   1.24518745e-04, ...,
          1.25271297e-04,   3.56316777e-05,   4.04627326e-06],
       [  4.91737483e-05,   2.60021159e-04,   8.61040782e-04, ...,
          8.63055116e-04,   2.61142646e-04,   4.95371969e-05],
       [  1.26523402e-04,   8.49825097e-04,   2.90915114e-03, ...,
          2.90881563e-03,   8.49568460e-04,   1.26304061e-04],
       ..., 
       [  1.28503540e-04,   8.52331228e-04,   2.91197700e-03, ...,
          2.91016186e-03,   8.51134886e-04,   1.28111642e-04],
       [  2.14206957e-05,   2.32703838e-04,   8.34190170e-04, ...,
          8.34319100e-04,   2.32750244e-04,   2.14206957e-05],
       [ -8.42595455e-06,   2.29651105e-05,   1.12404508e-04, ...,
          1.12760317e-04,   2.31778213e-05,  -8.35505125e-06]], dtype=float32)
```

Calling the scipy equivalent :

```
c_2 = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, b, "full").astype(np.float32)
c_2
```

Output :

```
array([[  5.47012860e-06,   3.68362089e-05,   1.26135841e-04, ...,
          1.26135841e-04,   3.68362089e-05,   5.47012769e-06],
       [  3.68362089e-05,   2.48057506e-04,   8.49407224e-04, ...,
          8.49407224e-04,   2.48057506e-04,   3.68362089e-05],
       [  1.26135841e-04,   8.49407224e-04,   2.90856976e-03, ...,
          2.90856976e-03,   8.49407224e-04,   1.26135841e-04],
       ..., 
       [  1.26135841e-04,   8.49407224e-04,   2.90856976e-03, ...,
          2.90856976e-03,   8.49407224e-04,   1.26135841e-04],
       [  3.68362089e-05,   2.48057506e-04,   8.49407224e-04, ...,
          8.49407224e-04,   2.48057506e-04,   3.68362089e-05],
       [  5.47012814e-06,   3.68362089e-05,   1.26135841e-04, ...,
          1.26135841e-04,   3.68362089e-05,   5.47012814e-06]], dtype=float32)
```

Checking the outputs :

```
c_1 == c_2
```

Gives :

```
array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

And :

```
np.allclose(c_1, c_2)
```

gives :

```
False
```

So the output is not correct. Removing the `fftshift` does not change a thing.

In my [project](https://github.com/aurelienpierre/Image-Cases-Studies/blob/efd145369a25796f040c9805cbdda7c544084d58/lib/deconvolution.pyx#L261), the scipy version gives a correct image, the pyfftw with my implementation gives blurry output.

**Edit**

I tested also in `double` type (`np.float64`) and while the raw result of the convolution is close enough (actually, scipy does the convolution in double), the picture is still bad :

Deconvolved with scipy :
[image]

Deconvolved with custom convolution here : it's not only blurry but you get fringes on the edges :
[image]

```
a = np.ones((6000, 4000), dtype='float64')
b = np.kaiser(25, 8)
b = np.outer(b, b).astype('float64')
```

Now :

```
np.allclose(c_1, c_2)
```

Returns :

```
True
```

What could give this result ?

Comment: BTW, that's a wrong wayt to compare arrays of floats see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVergaraKausel, I didn't know this one

Comment: SciPy doesn't use `fftw` due to license issues but uses `fftpack`. Hence there might be implementation differences most probably having a scalar `1/sqrt(n)`in front of the transformation etc. By the way you don't need a class to do this. It's just a function.

Comment: It seems that FFTW normalize automatically the FFT so that ifft(fft(a)) = a. Also, the way pyfftw makes the planning ahead of the transform makes the class necessary, the fft builders are not ufunc but memory planners.

Comment: You should update the question using the allclose function if it's still relevant that part. It appears to me that with pyfftw you observe an artifact, most likely a problem in the wrapping. Test what happens with something simpler like a sine or cosine.

Comment: Ah, you changed the description. Now it looks to me (not being an expert) that perhaps pyfftw can be doing a filter in frequency space (some sort of cutoff) thereby introducing blurriness.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel I added `np.allclose` output

Comment: Unless you properly pad the arguments, convolution using the FFT does *[circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution)*.  See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468307/scipy-ndimage-filters-convolve-and-multiplying-fourier-transforms-give-different).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your trimming technique is incorrect. You need to phase shift if you want to use the implicit trimming (by setting the transform size of the inverse) - this is pretty tricky to get right. Better is to invert the full size transform and snip out the middle. Also, your `fftshift`s are superfluous and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected :

```
class fftconvolve:
    def __init__(self, A, B, domain, threads=8):
        MK =  B.shape[0]
        NK = B.shape[1]
        M = A.shape[0]
        N = A.shape[1]

        if domain =="same":
            self.Y = M
            self.X = N
        elif domain == "valid":
            self.Y = M - MK + 1
            self.X = N - NK + 1
        elif domain == "full":
            self.Y = M + MK - 1
            self.X = N + NK - 1

        self.M = M + MK - 1
        self.N = N + NK - 1

        a = np.pad(A, ((0, MK - 1), (0, NK - 1)), mode='constant')
        b = np.pad(B, ((0, M - 1), (0, N - 1)), mode='constant')

        self.fft_A_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfft2(a, s=(self.M, self.N), threads=threads)
        self.fft_B_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfft2(b, s=(self.M, self.N), threads=threads)
        self.ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.irfft2(self.fft_A_obj.output_array, s=(self.M, self.N), threads=threads)


        self.offset_Y = int(np.floor((self.M - self.Y)/2))
        self.offset_X = int(np.floor((self.N - self.X)/2))

    def __call__(self, A, B):
        MK =  B.shape[0]
        NK = B.shape[1]
        M = A.shape[0]
        N = A.shape[1]

        a = np.pad(A, ((0, MK - 1), (0, NK - 1)), mode='constant')
        b = np.pad(B, ((0, M - 1), (0, N - 1)), mode='constant')

        return self.ifft_obj(self.fft_A_obj(a) * self.fft_B_obj(b))[self.offset_Y:self.offset_Y + self.Y, self.offset_X:self.offset_X + self.X]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, and thanks to the fact that I found myself looking for faster implementations of `fftconvolve`, I tried this with various examples and "same" convolution and found this to take twice the time `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` takes. What do you think it's the problem?

Comment: @CamiloMartinezM. Did you ever find the answer to this?